# Leak memory with dequeueReusableCell in custom table view cell

Tags: swift3, tableview

I have an issue with dequeueReusableCell in table view cell every time i scroll within tableView i get the memory leak when i use the instruments tools in Xcode it show me the leak in this function how can i solve this problem please help me to solve out this problem.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieCell") as! MovieTableViewCell

        // her for the button delete in cell
        // add target
        cell.changeFolderNameButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.changeFolderNameButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.changeFolderName(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        /////////////
        cell.imageViewCheckMark.isHidden = true
        cell.imageViewSelect.isHidden = true

        let getFile = ARRAYOFFOLDERS[indexPath.row]

        // for display the URL for each folder in the documents
        cell.URLFolderLabel.text = ARRAYOFFOLDERS[indexPath.row].absoluteString

        if getFile.pathExtension == "" {
            cell.imageViewCell.image = UIImage(named: "folder")
            cell.folderNameLabel.text = getFile.lastPathComponent
        }else{
            cell.imageViewCell.image = UIImage(named: "movie")
            cell.folderNameLabel.text = getFile.lastPathComponent
        }


        if ARRAY_HOLD_ALL_CELL_WITH_EMPTY_CIRCLE.count > 0 && STATUS_EDIT_BUTTON {
            // for show all the empty circle near to folder
            if ARRAY_HOLD_ALL_CELL_WITH_EMPTY_CIRCLE[indexPath.row] == indexPath.row {
                cell.imageViewSelect.isHidden = false
                cell.imageViewCheckMark.isHidden = true
            }
        }else if STATUS_EDIT_BUTTON == false && ARRAY_HOLD_ALL_CELL_WITH_EMPTY_CIRCLE.count > 0 {
            if ARRAY_HOLD_ALL_CELL_WITH_EMPTY_CIRCLE[indexPath.row] == indexPath.row {
                cell.imageViewSelect.isHidden = true
                cell.imageViewCheckMark.isHidden = true
            }
        }

        // for show the checkmark on the cell which user select it
        if STATUS_EDIT_BUTTON && DICTIONARY_OF_SELECT_FILE.count > 0 {
            if DICTIONARY_OF_SELECT_FILE[indexPath.row] == indexPath.row {
                cell.imageViewCheckMark.isHidden = false
                cell.imageViewSelect.isHidden = true
            }
        }else if STATUS_EDIT_BUTTON == false && DICTIONARY_OF_SELECT_FILE.count > 0 {
            if DICTIONARY_OF_SELECT_FILE[indexPath.row] == indexPath.row {
                cell.imageViewSelect.isHidden = true
                cell.imageViewCheckMark.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        ////////////////

        return cell

    }
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Probably isn't the cause, but you're using the old dequeue signature. You should use`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieCell", for: indexPath) as! MovieTableViewCell` instead

Comment: @AshleyMills I didn't know that. I just asked a question about that, if you know more about it can you please answer?

Comment: am also don't know how can i fix it